# Gitlab job failing - can't find docker command

Tags: docker, gitlab

When i try to run the `deploy` job on my gitlab pipeline, i get the following error;

```
$ docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p "$CI_BUILD_TOKEN" "$CI_REGISTRY"
/bin/bash: line 84: docker: command not found
```

My `gitlab-ci.yml` looks like this

```
image: docker:latest

services:
  - docker:dind

before_script:
  - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p "$CI_BUILD_TOKEN" "$CI_REGISTRY"

stages:
  - lint
  - test
  - build
  - build-image
  - deploy

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: registry.gitlab.com/username/someimage:latest
  script: 
    - some deploy command
  only:
    refs:
      - master
      - develop
      - staging
```

Comment: docker isn't supported as default on Gitlab CI. Can you tell me your purpose ?

Comment: @LeKhiem in the `deploy` job, I want to use a private docker image to perform the deployment but it seems the `docker` command is not available in the `deploy` job context

Comment: `image: docker:latest` what's this ? I guess you want to use docker image to deploy your code on Gitlab CI, for gitlab registry, I think you don't need to authenticate it.
OR you can use `image: docker:git`

Comment: @LeKhiem I'll try that

Comment: Does it work ? If not, please send me the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
image: docker:git

services:
  - docker:dind

before_script:
  - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN registry.gitlab.com

stages:
  - lint
  - test
  - build
  - build-image
  - deploy

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: registry.gitlab.com/username/someimage:latest
  script: 
    - apt update
    - ...
  only:
    refs:
      - master
      - develop
      - staging
```

Answer (score 1):

`docker login` from your `before_script` is executed in the container based on the private image you specified: `registry.gitlab.com/username/someimage:latest`

That image doesn't have `docker` installed, hence the error message.

Depending on your case, you can either:

- install docker in that image (wherever you create it)
- or right in the GitLab job as first lines `apt-get update && apt-get install docker.io` if it's Ubuntu based
- or use another image altogether, that already has docker

It really depends on what you want to achieve in the end.